# Why my blog redirects me to another website?

Tags: redirect, blogger, io-redirection

Why my blog redirects me to another url ?

```
I installed a template on my blog and i adjusted on it ,but when i open my blog website the blog redirect me to another URL, i looked for the redirected URL but not found and i did not find the both of redirection code and the redirected url.
```

how can i slove this issue ?

here is my blog :

- https://germanpath.blogspot.com/

Comment: I don't think you'll receive an answer if you ask in this way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a page that explains how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking you to a different website that is malware in the theme you plugged in

Comment: you could have added this as a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33633538)